# Where can I find out the classpath of my J2EE application in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, eclipse-classpath

I have a J2EE project developed in eclipse. How do find out what is the class path of this project?

Comment: There is a _Show Command Line_ button in Java run/debug configurations for that.

Answer (score 0):

if you want get absolute classpath in your disc:

Animal animal = new Animal();
System.out.println(animal.getClass().getResource(""));